# What is 'Claw Chief'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The expression is from the below text. (['Ravished Armenia'](https://books.google.com/books?id=NMtDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA133&dq="Claw+chief") published in 1918)

> In the vicinity of Malatia, and in the city itself, there were more
>   than twenty thousand refugees waiting to be sent on. Kurds were
>   camped outside in little bands, each with its **“Claw chief,”** waiting
>   to waylay and plunder the exiles. Arabs rode about the hills in the
>   distance--outlaw bands, who swooped down upon the Christians in the
>   night and stole the strongest of the women and girls for the harvesting
>   in the fields.

From the context, I just guess the meaning is kind of 'sub-chief'.
However, I can't find this expression from anywhere in the dictionaries.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My first reaction was that is was a typo for "Clan Chief", but it may possibly be an actual term which means something like "Bey".

Comment: If it isn't a typo, then it is probably a literal translation into English of a local term, in which case the English has no meaning.

Comment: Both of you may be right.  That's what I have thought of it.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression "claw chief" does not seem to be a typographical error. A Google Books search turns up matches for the term in two other books (besides *Ravished Armenia*). One match occurs in "[Memorandum Forwarded by a Foreign Resident at H.](https://books.google.com/books?id=7qafAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA265&dq=%22claw+chief%22+Kurds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRorGxhJ3bAhWWHjQIHV5KC6AQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22claw%20chief%22%20Kurds&f=false)" in Arnold Toynbee, *The Treatment of Armenians in the Ottoman Empire: Documents Presented to Viscount Grey of Fallodon, Secretary of State for Foreign Affairs* (1916):

> The thirteenth day the caravan was at Malatia, but for one hour only, for they returned tp the village of AP., two hours from Malatia. Here the policemen deserted them altogether, after taking them about 200 liras in toll for the protection they had given them that far, and the people were left to the mercy of the beastly Bey (**claw-chief**) of the Kurds of Aghja-Daghi.

Eight other matches for "claw chief" appear in William Chad, [*One Nation Under Seige: A World War One Era True Story of Survival and Valor*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZdTfAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&dq=%22claw+chief%22+Kurds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRorGxhJ3bAhWWHjQIHV5KC6AQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22claw%20chief%22%20&f=false). Unfortunately, Chad's book is so badly written that its use of "claw chief" eight times is less impressive than it would otherwise be. A sample:

> In the irrevocable past, legends assert that Saints have hidden inside the *Een Dara* from their pursuing enemies, including St. Bartholomew, one of the Twelve Apostles of Jesus. Prior to World War One, *The Canyon* was used as a hideout by brigands and marauding *Chethiji*. In fact **Claw Chief**, one of the most bestial, kill-crazed, barbarous Kurdish cutthroats of the district, who was often called upon was often called upon by the local Officialdom to fulfill the promise of *Jihad* against 'the Christian pigs in our midst', has maintained his headquarters in there for a long time.

It's not a good sign when you misspell—both on the book's cover and on its title page—one of the four words in your book's main title.

Fortunately, an Elephind search turns up another relevant match. From Aurora Mardiganian, "[My Two Years of Torture in Ravished, Martyred Armenia](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84026749/1918-09-22/ed-1/seq-26/#words=%22claw+chief%22)," in the *Washington [D.C.] Times* (September 18, 1918):

> We did not know where we were being taken, nor to what. After many hours of riding I was shifted to the care of a Kurd who would answer my pleading questions. He told me a great pacha was at Egin, a city to the north; that he had come down from Constantinople especially to take an interest in pretty Armenian girls. That lie even paid money to have Christian girls who were healthy and pleasing brought before him. And that the "**claw chief**"—the lesser Kurdish chieftain—was taking us to Egin to this Pacha.

My 1972 edition of the complete *Oxford English Dictionary* doesn't include an entry for "claw chief," so I don't doubt that it ever registered as a naturalized English term. Further complicating the situation: when I asked Google Translate to translate the Turkish word *bey* (mentioned in close connection with "claw-chief" Toynbee's collection, above) into Kurdish, the translated word that emerged was *bey*. Still, the connection between "claw-chief" and *bey* seems very close. Here is the entry for *bey* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **bey** *n* {Turk[ish] gentleman, chief} (1537) **1 a :** a provincial governor in the Ottoman Empire **b :** the former native ruler of Tunis or Tunisia **2**—used as a courtesy title in Turkey and Egypt.

In the instances quoted above, none of the "claw-chiefs"—including "the beastly Bey of the Kurds of Aghja-Daghi"—seem to possess so lofty a rank as provincial governor, but even so they appear to be formidable chieflets within their home territories, whether through inheritance (similarly to a sheikh) or through self-made power (similarly to the head of a local militia or a band of brigands).